# Using a method on a angular mat-cell

Tags: angular, mat-table

I would like to call a method inside a mat-cell:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="complexity">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Complexidade</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ep"> {{ getElemenaryProcessComplexity(ep) }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

The method getElementaryProcessComplexity is used to calculate a value on the server side and return a string.

The problem is that the method getElementaryProcessComplexity is called infinite times.
[image]

Could someone help me?
I want to calculate a value on server side and show this value in a mat-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run everytime change detection runs you want an observable.

In your service have a method that returns an observable from the http call.

```
getData() => this.http.get('dataUrl');
```

and in you component expose it as an observable

```
data$ = this.myService.getData();
```

and in the template use the async pipe to view the data once it is available.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ep"> {{ data$ | async }} </td>
```

or you could have a pipe that returns an observable for `ep`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getElemenaryProcessComplexity'
})
export class GetElemenaryProcessComplexityPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  transform(ep): Observable<EpType> {
    return this.http.get('url/' + ep);
  }
}
```

and use it in the template with

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ep"> {{ ep | getElemenaryProcessComplexity | async }} </td>
```

The pipe will only create a single observable for each ep

Comment: I think I can't use the first solution because I should to pass parameters from the front end to the back end. So, I don't know how to do it on "data$ = this.myService.getData()". The parameter is on each line of the mat-table.

Comment: What you really should be doing is returning all the data with a single API call. Round tripping the API is poor design.

Comment: The values I want to retrieve from API are not stored in DB. They are calculated according I add itens in the mat-table. I can duplicate the methods to calculate the values on the back and front end. However, I would not like to do it. So, I'm trying to call the API to calculate these values to the front end.

Comment: Using the second suggested solution, the transform method is returning a object observable, not the JSON. So, the mat-cell are showing  "[object Object]".

Comment: Look at my Pipe: export class GetElementaryProcessComplexityPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  transform(ep): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.api + '/elementary_process/xxx');
  }

}

Comment: Use `this.http.get(environment.api + '/elementary_process/xxx').pipe(map(result => functionThatExtractsDataYouNeedFromResult(val)))`

Comment: Or if you want the json use the json pipe `{{ ep | getElemenaryProcessComplexity | async | json }}`